# ElasticSearch.Net dll quarantine from Antivirus - WS.Reputation.1

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, web-applications, symantec

Symantec Antivirus quarantines the ElasticSearch.Net dll and brings the web application down as access denied error is raised.

ElasticSearch.NET Version : 2.3.1

Symantec Version : 12.1.6

I have added in exceptions however I need to know why elasticsearch dlls are quarantined.

Comment: Only Symantec support will be able to tell you why it's engine deems this dll as not trustworthy. It might be that it is only considered potentially harmful because it was copied from an unsecure (network) location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can report this false positive to Symantec to have it properly resolved:

https://submit.symantec.com/false_positive/

Answer (score 2):

if you are sure about this dll, restore it from the quarantine, and white list it.
Or you can reload elasticsearch from a trusted server.